# Share axis from one of multiple subplots

Tags: python

I have subpolts with a size of 5*4，I am using Loop to write data on them. I'd like to share the x and y-axis for all of them from two specific subplots. If I use sharex  or sharey = True, they only share the xy from the last subplot. How could I do it?

```
basedir = Path(r"D:\Brown research\Task2 site selection\All_excel")
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5, 4, figsize=(10, 10))
for xlfile, ax in zip(basedir.glob("*.xlsx"), axes.flat):
    df = pandas.read_excel(xlfile) 
    x =  newdf['slope'] 
    y = newdf['AI']
    nbins = 10
    cm = ax.hist2d(x,y,nbins,cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, cmin=1,norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
#may add some code here to share y from subplot(5,4,13) and share x from subplot(5,4,20)
plt.savefig("AI_Slopew_sharexy.png", dpi=300)
```

Comment: Can you provide your actual working code that you want the community modify?

Comment: Hi Vincent, please see the code, thank you!